# Adapter not display content

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to populate data from my main activity using the adapter below. When i run the   activity the screen remains blanked. I believe it has to do with the ArrayList which is null perhaps. Can someone tell me why my data is not being displayed. am on this bug for three days now :/

```
public class CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {

    ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>();
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    Convertor main;

    public CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.count_layout, NO_RESOURCE);
        setItemTextResource(R.id.country_name);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(PostList.get(index).getDevise(), img);
        System.out.println("get item count:"+getItemsCount() );

        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lib);
        text.setText(PostList.get(index).getQuotite());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return  PostList.toArray().length;
    }


    @Override
    protected CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        return PostList.get(index).getDevise().toString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In my Main class i have already an

```
ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>();
```

which is populated.

Here is my main class that is my convertor.class

```
ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.convertor);
        context = this;

        text_devise_two = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_spacetwo);       

        final WheelView country = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.country);
        country.setVisibleItems(10);
        country.setViewAdapter(new FirstWheelAdapter(this));


        edt_validate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_validate);

        current_type_loc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_type_loc);
        refresh_header= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.refresh_header);

        //set current time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        refresh_header.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.mise_a_jour)+" "+formattedDate);

        image_one = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_one);
        image_two = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_two);

        final WheelView currency = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.currency);
        currency.setVisibleItems(10);
        currency.setViewAdapter(new CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter(this));

        country.addChangingListener(new OnWheelChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {

                if (!scrolling) {


                }
            }
        });

        country.addScrollingListener( new OnWheelScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {

                scrolling = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {

                scrolling = false;
                //1.
                wheelSelector(country.getCurrentItem());

            }
        });


        currency.addScrollingListener( new OnWheelScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {

                scrolling = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {

                scrolling = false;
                //1.
                secondWheel(currency.getCurrentItem());
            }
        });



        country.setCurrentItem(1);
        currency.setCurrentItem(3);
        new loadingTask().execute();
    }

    /*1. Change currency */
    public void wheelSelector (int id){

        if (id==0){

            current_type_loc.setText("EUR");
            image_one.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eur);

        }else {

            current_type_loc.setText("USD");
            image_one.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.usd);

        }
    }

    class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

          @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Convertor.this, "", "Chargement en cours..", true);

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pd.dismiss();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(getxml,"", Parser.xmlParser());

            taux = doc.select("taux");

            for (int i = 0; i < taux.size(); i++) {

                PostList.add(new convertor_pst(taux.get(i).getElementsByTag("devise").text().toString(),
                        taux.get(i).getElementsByTag("dateCours").text().toString(),
                        taux.get(i).getElementsByTag("libelle").text().toString(),
                        taux.get(i).getElementsByTag("quotite").text().toString(),
                        taux.get(i).getElementsByTag("fixing").text().toString()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             envelope =
                    "soap content"

            String requestEnvelope=String.format(envelope, "28-03-2013","true");
            getxml = Util.CallWebService(URL,SOAP_ACTION,requestEnvelope);
            System.out.println(getxml);

            return null; 

        }
    }


    public void secondWheel(int index){

        text_devise_two.setText(PostList.get(index).getDevise());
        edt_validate.setText("   "+PostList.get(index).getFixing());

    }

    /*
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
     * check if activity go to background
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        if (Util.isApplicationBroughtToBackground(Convertor.this)==true){
            startActivity(new Intent(Convertor.this,Compte.class));
        }

    }


}
```

This is the original wheel adapter class

```
public class CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {

    ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    // Countries names
    private String countries[] =
            new String[] {"EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD"};

    // Countries flags
    private int flags[] = new int[] {R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd};

    /**
     * Constructor
     */

    Convertor main;

    public CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.count_layout, NO_RESOURCE);
        setItemTextResource(R.id.country_name);

    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        img.setImageResource(flags[index]);

        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lib);
        text.setText("code");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return  countries.length;
    }


    @Override
    protected CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        return countries[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does you `System.out.println()` say? Does it log? And where do you set `PostList` with real data? You just have an empty list there. You need a setter method or a parameter in your constructor to set the list with some prefetched data...

Comment: yes i have my setter and getter in convertor_pst.class. No it does not log at all

Comment: Again: Your `PostList` variable is just an empty list. There is no data do show! You need to set or fill this list with some data!

Comment: how ? my ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>(); has data already set from my main activity class

Comment: At first sight your adapter looks ok to me. Please post the code where you use the adapter. Your update just shows that PostList exist but not that PostList is filled up with data

Comment: give me a few minutes i'll post it

Comment: check the update but this class is ok i received the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand

```
currency.setViewAdapter(new CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter(this));
```

this line creates the adapter, but you fill it up at this line :

```
new loadingTask().execute();
```

which is after, so you must call

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on your adapter to update the data.

Android Developer Help says

> notifyDataSetChanged()
>   Notifies the attached observers that the
>   underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set
>   should refresh itself.

So in your case you must

1. create an adapter (yourAdapter = new CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter ....)
2. assign it with the setViewAdater (WheelView.setViewAdapter(yourAdapter))
3. in the "postExecute" of your async task, do a call with yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

By the way, I am not sure to understand what you are doing, but in case you need to have a set of data displayed at two different locations, you don't need to duplicate (create a copy). The two list display can share the same adapter.

**UPDATE**

You have done an update to your question and I answer to that update :

In the original adapter the countries are not loaded in the async task. So when you assign the adapter, the display show the correct values because they are present in the adapter at the moment you assign it.

In your case, you load the values in the async task. When you create the adapter it is empty and you assign it empty, so the display shows an empty list. You should notify your display of the data change.

So in the original, no need to notify as the data is the correct one at the time of assignment. In your case you have to implement a notifyDataSetChanged(). Or change the type of adapter you are extending.

Comment: i've set CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter convert; as global, then in increate() i did this convert = new (CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter()); and finally in postExecute i called convert.notifyDataSetChanged(); ok. but on this postExecute line i am receiving an error Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ".", delete this token
 - The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type 
  CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter

Comment: maybe it is that AbstractWheelTextAdapter that i extend

Comment: wait i'll post the original wheel check my updates orignially this work

Comment: @yakusha please enlighten us with the solution. It might help other people with similar issues.

Comment: i created a constructor public CopyOfSecondWheelAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<convertor_pst> d) {
  super(a, R.layout.count_layout, NO_RESOURCE);
  data = d; }

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, you have 2 times a variable name `PostList` which confuses you. One is created in your activity and one in your adapter and ass you call `add()` to the variable of your activity, the list in your adapter never gets the items.

Create a setter for the list in your adapter and set the list in your `onPostExecute()`.